# What is the scientific term for unexpected, spontaneous dream recall?

Tags: terminology, memory, sleep, dreams, long-term-memory

**I'm interested if there's a term for spontaneous dream recall**. I will try to define the phenomenon I'm talking about.

Over 10 years ago, I started to notice that I can spontaneously recall dreams, and clearly label them as dreams. I may **recall 3 dreams from the past night, then more dreams from weeks or months ago**. Some of these dreams I have written down, others were "forgotten" upon awakening, only to be recalled much later. That's a lot of dreams. When in this state of spontaneous recall, I can consciously guide the recall process once the original dream is recalled and recall a number of additional dreams that may or may not be loosely connected to that one.

Just to clarify, these are not fantasies and neither waking memories. I can clearly distinguish a waking memory from a dream memory. The entire dream memory is recalled in a flash with all the details: place, action, characters present. All of this over a second or so, similar in duration to the [Deja-vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deja-vu).

I've looked up and found [Cryptomnesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptomnesia), which is defined as:

> Cryptomnesia occurs when a forgotten memory returns without it being
>   recognised as such by the subject, who believes it is something new
>   and original.

What I'm describing is similar to Cryptomnesia, except that the memory is immediately recognized as a previously seen dream.

This phenomenon makes me believe that I do not really "forget" dreams. Normally, such memories are "blocked" from ordinary awareness, but can be recalled at random times of the day, or when laying in bed and preparing for sleep. Just to clarify: I calculated that I potentially see up to 1600 dreams in a year, and can recall many of them this way.

**Is there a search term I can use to look at scientific literature that deals with the phenomenon of unbidden, spontaneous (dream)memory recall?** Maybe there's something that deals with real memory recall that sounds similar?

Comment: I'm currently researching this subject too, as I have found in the passing months that I've had dreams come back to me as vivid as memories. I remember them as dreams, not events that have happened in my life when I have been awake. There doesn't seem to be any specific stimulus for a dream memory to be triggered. I do suffer from depression and have recently undergone over a year of severe trauma, I began thinking this dreams memory occurrence was just my mind breaking down, with an inability to deal with all that is going on. I would be interested to hear if you found out more.

Comment: (continuation of user3533's answer converted to comment) .. "From what I can tell people who can usually recall memories, facts, etc at whim are very intelligent, but this is not what I'm experiencing. I've been looking specifically at hypermnesia."

Comment: Over the past couple years I've noticed that this kind of phenomenon happens with random real life events too, like recalling a street or place in a childhood town. Unlike events listed in the involuntary memory article (eating cake triggering childhood memories of eating cake), there's absolutely nothing I can think of that can be considered a trigger for this kind of memory recall phenomenon

Comment: Since last time I saw this question, I've discovered that my brain/mind occasionally recalls a childhood rhyme or saying in my native language related to what I'm perceiving in the real world. For example, seeing a muscular avatar in a videogame, I can recall a childhood rhyme about a muscular man. It took me some time to notice this, as these rhymes have been forgotten for over 20 years, and I don't try to recall them, they just arise. Similar things happen with real life memories, although I have not found a definitive cue that triggers them

Comment: I haven't experienced this per se, but have noticed that when I meditate, memories that I haven't been aware of for a long time just pop up out of nowhere - I usually associate it with a relaxing/release of the physical body - that might be a trigger.

Comment: I have a hypothesis that the recall is caused by triggering of neural networks that were active during the dream. It seems the network stays active for a short period of time and thus it is possible to recall related dreams for a short period of time after the exposure. I've also confirmed that I'm not the only one recalling childhood sayings in response to real life events.

Comment: I started spontaneously recalling dreams when I started taking Nuvigil for daytime fatigue (about 8 years ago). This went on for a few years. The dreams were most certainly dreams not real life memories. Also I could not tell how long ago I'd had them but I did sense a feeling that some where maybe > 20-30 years ago. Also, once recalled they tend to stay as a more permanent memory. While still taking Nuvigil, the recollections have stopped now for some time. I have to say I'm rather pleased as the spontaneous nature of the recollection and instant feeling associated with them could be quite di

Comment: This might be an old post, but I found you. I have been recalling almost every dream I've ever had. All imaginary, none of them were "real", but when I'm trying to go to sleep, they all pop in my head and I'm fully awake. I even look forward to thinking of as many as I can just to fall asleep. These are dreams of places I've never been, things I've never done, but I remember dreaming about them, some years ago, and I remember every detail now. How does that happen? I thought it was kind of cool, but now I think there's more to it...

Answer (score 10):

This could be an example of what is termed ["involuntary memory" or "involuntary autobiographical memory"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involuntary_memory).  Mainly it is due to subtle and obvious prompts.