# Are there studies on the effect of nicotine patches on dream vividness and dream recall?

Tags: neuroscience, dreams, neuro-transmitters

Acetylcholine plays an important role during REM Sleep. I cite an [answer](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/12257/370) to the question "Why do dreams lose clarity quickly over time after we awaken?":

> Activity in the PFC during sleep may be modulated by levels of acetylcholine, dopamine, and other neurotransmitters.

See references and links there. Nicotine also binds to ACh receptors.

Are there studies on the effect of nicotine patches worn while sleeping on dream vividness and dream recall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the only one that's easy to find in google scholar, but there might be more:

Page, F., Coleman, G., & Conduit, R. (2006). [The effect of transdermal nicotine patches on sleep and dreams](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031938406001697). *Physiology & Behavior*, *88*(4), 425-432.

Comment: Great. Thanks. The citing articles and recommended stuff gives more interesting references...